# rails 3 writing a controller method to check what type is current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a method in my application controller that would be available to all the controllers.  It is a simple roles thing.

```
def user_is_admin
    if current_user.admin == true
    end
  end
```

If the current logged in user has .admin set to true than this method should return true.

Then in my controller I am doing:
before_filter :user_is_admin, :only => [show]

While the code is not erroring, its also not protecting the page from being viewed.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the before_filter to do something to interrupt the action if the current user is not an admin.

```
def user_is_admin
    if current_user.admin != true
        redirect_to <some_other_action> 
        return false
    end
end
```

Note that this is checking that the current_user is NOT an admin.
Alternately, you could raise an exception or render an error template without redirecting:

```
def user_is_admin
    if current_user.admin != true
        raise "Admin required"
    end
end
```

or

```
def user_is_admin
    if current_user.admin != true
        render :template => 'shared/admin_required'
        return false
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for something different then what your code is doing.

What you would want your method to do, is something like this:

```
def user_is_admin
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "You do not have sufficient privileges for that!" unless current_user.admin
end
```

Where `root_url` is where they would be redirected. You still need the before_filter.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, not sure why I didn't type it like that :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
def user_is_admin
  redirect_to "/" unless current_user.admin
end
```